# High Availability Active-Active Database Design

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am trying to design a HA solution for an active-active site. Basically, Site A and Site B are both writing to the same table in a database that is position outside of Site A and B. This database is use in an event when either Site A or B fails, it could be use as a backed up. MySQL is being used here.

So i am wondering is there any solution/software out there that is able to handle concurrent updates from Site A & B to the same table.

Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood what you are trying to do correctly, MySQL will be able to handle inserts/updates from multiple sites without any additional software.

Having a second database that replicates the main database as a backup, and can be used as the main db if the first database fails, will probably be a minimum requirement for high availability as well.  Have a look at MySQLs own MySQL Cluster as well.